# Do we ever see a pregnant crewmember on TNG?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

Other than Troi in The Child, do we ever see a pregnant crewmember of the Enterprise D? Of course we see Keiko pregnant, but she's a civilian. I'm trying to imagine a maternity uniform.

Comment: I think there have been at DS9, but on TNG I cannot remmeber any.

Comment: @frlan: Kira! Sneezing!

Comment: Yepp.... Kira ;)

Comment: Keiko O'Brien was a botanist on the Enterprise, she wasn't Star Fleet but she might have been considered crew as she was carrying out research when she meet Miles. She became pregnant and Worf delivered her baby in 10-Fwd.

Comment: @HikaruIchijyo: Great scene! Worf: "You may now give birth!" Btw: Does Spot count? Afterall he/she assists Data in his research by sometimes not jumping on his computer while he is working...

Comment: @HikaruIchijyo: You make a fair point.  Would Keiko be considered "crew" even though she wasn't Star Fleet?  It is clear she was on the Enterprise conducting some kind of research originally... Hmmm

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Nurse Ogawa was pregnant through Season 7.
[image: Nurse Alyssa Ogawa in maternity uniform]

Troi was pregnant with an alien child for about 5 minutes in Season 2's opener "The Child", so as you say that doesn't count. ;-)
[image: Counselor Deanna Troi pregnant in robe with Data]

Comment: Yes, that is right I recall Qgawa was pregnant in Episode 19 of S7 “Genesis”  I believe that may have been a plot-point in that episode.

Comment: Indeed it was. Not only that, it was the MacGuffin that saved the crew! Not bad for an unborn child.

Comment: AHA! I'm watching Genesis now. :)

Comment: Of course she's not showing yet, darn-it.

Comment: Alyssa Ogawa was pregnant in All Good Things too.  Was it the same as the baby in Genesis or did she get pregnant twice?

Comment: @Stefan: Alyssa Ogawa had just found out about her pregnancy in *Genesis*, and there were only five other episodes between *Genesis* and *All Good Things*, i.e. a few weeks up to very few months in series time. So, it definitely is the same pregnancy (Ogawa's appearance in *All Good Things* is quite short and is definitely meant to briefly pick up her storyline from *Genesis*).

Comment: @Jolenealaska: Actually, there is this shot of Ogawa: [TNG maternity uniform](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/File:Starfleet_maternity_uniform,_2370.jpg)

Comment: YAY! That's a TNG maternity uniform, by golly! Where are her pips?

Answer (score 15):

In ST:VOY, [Samantha Wildman](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Samantha_Wildman) was pregnant (over multiple episodes). Admittedly this is not exactly Enterprise D, but as you wrote "I'm trying to imagine a maternity uniform", it might be helpful:

[image: Neelix (in his chef's hat and apron) helping Samantha Wildman as she's having some kind of discomfort while sitting by a window in the mess hall; Wildman is wearing a standard science officer uniform while pregnant.]
[image: Neelix talking to Samantha Wildman as she works on a PADD in the mess hall. Neelix is bent forward clutching a metalic thermos. A metalic cub is on the table Samantha is sitting at.]

He's a description of the costume from Screen Used:

> This costume was made by the production for use by Nancy Hower in the role of the pregnant xenobiologist "Ensign Samantha Wildman" in the episode “Deadlock”. **The costume is a standard type-B Starfleet uniform altered for maternity; long-sleeved, full-length, jumpsuit that has the usual gray undershirt attached to black jumpsuit pants with stirrups for the feet, a long-sleeved, pleated, black Starfleet tunic, Sciences Blue division strip, a Velcro patch on the left breast for a comm badge** (not included), Velcro cuff adjustment, a zipper down the front, is open at the bottom. A sewn in tag reads "Voyager, Nancy Hower". Minor wear from use is present and two very small holes are located above the left chest and a small hole on the side of the right leg above the ankle.

You can see more detailed photos of the uniform [here](http://www.screenused.com/?sectionID=item-detail&subsectionID=index.cfm&item_id=12714), but they're watermarked. The maternity alternation makes the jumpsuit look like separate top and pants because of added loose fabric that drapes over the abdomen. Apparently, you can also buy the actual costume for $1,249.

Comment: Apparently the episode Tattoo focuses on her pregnancy, so maybe it's worth a look to see if it shows a maternity uniform. :)

Comment: If it doesn't have to be TNG... There is B'elanas pregnancy, Kiras pregnancy (different uniform)... and certainly there are still more!

Comment: @Jolenealaska: As you'd expect, it's just a standard science officer uniform with adjustments for the larger belly.

Comment: Actually, I take that back. It differs form the standard jumpsuit in that it looks more like a two-piece than the jumpsuit because of the maternity alterations.

Comment: Yep, it's not my beloved D, but it does give a pretty good idea what the uniform would look like.

Answer (score 3):

In Voyager, Kes was seen giving birth to hers and Tom Paris' daughter in an alternate future in an episode "Before and After."